# Calculating determinant of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have to calculate the determinant of the following matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}
a&b&c&d\\b&-a&d&-c\\c&-d&-a&b\\d&c&-b&-a
\end{pmatrix}

Using following hint:

**Calculate determinant of matrix $AA^{T}$ and use the theorem that
$\det(AB) = \det A \cdot \det B$**

I simply don't see how can I use this hint in this calculation.

Comment: Have you got the product $AA^T$? If yes, please include it in the text of the quesiton. Also, do you know how $\det A^T$ and $\det A$ are related?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We have
$$AA^T=(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)I_4$$
then
$$\det(A)^2=\det (AA^T)=(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^4$$
hence
$$\det(A)=-(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2$$
and we choose the negative sign since the $\det$ function is continuous with its components and $\det(A)=-1$ in the case $a=1$ and $b=c=d=0$

Comment: Thanks for the tip about sign of the result : )

Comment: @Świstak35 you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little hint:

$$\det(A^T) = \det(A).$$

This makes the questions a lot shorter. Can you think how?

Comment: **Answer here:**
$AA^{T}$ just looks like big, boring to calculate matrix. In fact, almost all fields in matrix are reducing to 0's, and in result we have a matrix which has nonzero values only on it's main diagonal. Thus, our determinent is product of values on main diagonal.

Then, using that $det A^{T} = det A$ the result is easy to calculate. Thanks!