# Matrix Determinant with trigonometry

Tags: matrices, determinant

**How do i find the determinant of this matrix:**

$$\left(%
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \cos (a)    & \sin(a)\cos(b) & \sin(a)\sin(b) \\
 -\sin(a)     & \cos(a)\cos(b) & \cos(a)\sin(b) \\
  0&  -\sin(b)        & \cos(b)  \\
\end{array}%
\right)$$

I tried to solve it, but i can't get the right answer. Any help ?

Comment: Where do you get stuck? If you show your efforts, it's easier to point you in the right direction.

Comment: this is what have i done so far : cos^2(a)cos^2(b ) - cos^2(a)sin^2(b) + sin^2(a)cos^2(b) + sin^2(a)sin(b)cos(b)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating determinant of matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408397/calculating-determinant-of-matrix)

Comment: i'm not that good with trigonometry though,

Comment: Perhaps your problem is not with how to find the determinant but how to simplify the expression you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have
$$\cos^2(a)\cos^2(b)-\cos^2(a)\sin^2(b)+\sin^2(a)\cos^2(b)+\sin^2(a)\sin(b)\cos(b),$$
which is pretty close, but not entirely correct. So first of all, go back to the $3\times3$ determinant formula and recheck and correct your calculation.

In the expression above, the first and third terms are correct. And you can simplify them by factoring out the common factor and using a trig identity:
$$\cos^2(a)\cos^2(b)+\sin^2(a)\cos^2(b)=[\cos^2(a)+\sin^2(a)]\cos^2(b)=1\cdot\cos^2(b)=\cos^2(b).$$
After you correct the other two terms, you'll be able to simplify further in a similar fashion.

Comment: as a matter of fact the answer of this determinant on my book its 0, it is sure that cos^2(b) it's the right answer?

Comment: Set $a = b = 0$ and look at the resulting matrix. Is its determinant zero?

Comment: @RediRamaj: Did I say that it is the answer? That's what **part** of the expression simplifies to. You still need to do the rest of the work.

Comment: @zipirovich ok i get it thnx

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the columns are pairwise orthogonal.

Comment: thanks for the hint, but i don't understand quite well english terminology about maths, could you be more specific

Comment: Not until you show us the work you've already done, to help convince me that I'm not just doing your homework for you. Also: you can google "pairwise definition" and "orthogonal definition".

Comment: this is what have i done so far : cos^2(a)cos^2(b ) - cos^2(a)sin^2(b) + sin^2(a)cos^2(b) + sin^2(a)sin(b)cos(b)........and you're not doing my homework i can assure u

Comment: and i used the pairwise rule

Answer (score 1):

> $$\begin{vmatrix}
>  \cos a    & \sin a \cos b & \sin a\sin b \\
>  -\sin a     & \cos a\cos b & \cos a\sin b \\
>   0&  -\sin b       & \cos b  \\
> \end{vmatrix}$$

Expand along the first column (careful for the extra minus-sign for $-\sin a$) to get:

$$= \cos a\begin{vmatrix}
 \color{blue}{\cos a}\cos b & \color{blue}{\cos a}\sin b \\
  -\sin b       & \cos b  \\
\end{vmatrix}+\sin a\begin{vmatrix}
\color{red}{\sin a} \cos b & \color{red}{\sin a}\sin b \\
-\sin b       & \cos b  \\
\end{vmatrix}$$
Now notice the common factor $\color{blue}{\cos a}$ in the first row of the first $2 \times 2$-determinant and the common factor $\color{red}{\sin a}$ in the first row of the second $2 \times 2$-determinant; pull them out:

$$=\cos^2 a\begin{vmatrix}
 \cos b & \sin b \\
  -\sin b       & \cos b  \\
\end{vmatrix}+\sin^2 a\begin{vmatrix}
 \cos b & \sin b \\
-\sin b       & \cos b  \\
\end{vmatrix}$$

The two $2 \times 2$-determinants simplify to the formula $\cos^2b+\sin^2b=1$ and you're nearly there.

Answer (score 0):

solve the matrix along column 1:

$$cos(a)[cos(a)cos(b)*cos(b)-(-sin(b)*(cos(a)sin(b)))]-(-sin(a))[(sin(a)cos(b)*(cos(a)sin(b)))-(cos(a)cos(b)*(sin(a)sin(b)))]+0$$

answer$=-sin^2(a) sin^2(b) + cos^2(a) cos^2(b) + sin^2(a) cos^2(b) - cos^2(a) sin^2(b)$